# Subtract first two rows only for each value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a specific query to run which should subtract two rows from each other. It shouldn't subtract the entire row but only the fields specified. The data I'm trying to subtract is organized like so:

```
object # |       timestamp     | input_rate1 | output_rate1 | ...

   obj1  | 2011-07-20 05:53:33 |    349393   |    25843     | ...

   obj1  | 2011-07-20 05:23:20 |    222293   |    11019     | ...
```

The result would then be `00:30:13 |  127100 | 48824  .`

I found a post that showed how to do this but the difference between their data and mine is that mine does not have an id field that can keep track what line I'm at. I tried using the row_number() but my sql server doesn't support it.

Is this even possible without using the id field? I forgot to mention that each object has more than two timestamp records, but I really only need to do it for the two latest.

Comment: I take it this is for multiple objects, so for every obj-id this should happen?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes. I'm currently stuck at this problem. Edgar below pointed me in the correct direction to get the maximum time stamp row associated with each  obj-id. How would I get the second row for every obj-id? I tried using limit 1,1 but that only seems to return the second result for the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the two latest this ugly query should do it:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(FIRSTTIME.timestamp,SECONDTIME.timestamp), FIRSTTIME.inputrate1 - SECONDTIME.inputrate1, FIRSTTIME.outputrate1 - SECONDTIME.outputrate1
FROM
((SELECT * FROM `table` HAVING timestamp = max(timestamp)) as FIRSTTIME,
(SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY TIMESTAMP LIMIT 1,1) as SECONDTIME)
```

Comment: I was able to get the max timestamp row associated with each obj-id, but I'm having trouble getting the row below the max (if desc) for each obj-id.

Comment: (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY TIMESTAMP LIMIT 1,1) that gets it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(FIRSTTIME.timestamp,SECONDTIME.timestamp), FIRSTTIME.inputrate1 - SECONDTIME.inputrate1, FIRSTTIME.outputrate1 - SECONDTIME.outputrate1 FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM tableNAME WHERE objectNumber = 'obj1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC) A, 
  (SELECT * FROM A WHERE MAX(timestamp) FIRSTTIME, 
  (SELECT * FROM A WHERE MIN(timestamp)) SECONDTIME
```

You may need to bear with me a little, I use Oracle and SQL mainly so I am not sure if I used a function I am not allowed.
I think you have to use limit instead of top.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(FIRSTTIME.timestamp,SECONDTIME.timestamp), FIRSTTIME.inputrate1 - SECONDTIME.inputrate1, FIRSTTIME.outputrate1 - SECONDTIME.outputrate1 FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tableNAME WHERE objectNumber = 'obj1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC) LIMIT 2) A, 
  (SELECT * FROM A WHERE MAX(timestamp) FIRSTTIME, 
  (SELECT * FROM A WHERE MIN(timestamp)) SECONDTIME
```